Laravel routing conflict to public's folder
I am developing project using laravel 
and I have directory named 'profile' in public folder. 
also I have route named /profile also 
Route::get('/profile', [UserController::class ,'showProfile']);

when I visit 'localhost/profile' url, it goes to public/profile folder
I have 2 ubuntu server.
this project works well on one server, but not working on other one.
please help me...

You'll have to rename one or the other. It's a naming conflict, and you can't have both.

What does the code in showProfile method of the UserController do?

The general convention for utilising the public directory would be to create some subdirectory, generally assets in order to use the assets helper, and populate this deeper.
This is exactly what asset bundlers like vite will do and helps keep that initial namespace clean.
If you are using this to directly store images for a users profile, for instance, using a publicly accessible storage disk may be a more effective way of managing this content

The problem is that the web server initially tries to open a directory or file at the specified URL with that name. And if the file or directory is not found, it passes the address processing to the Laravel application.
You can override this behavior by hardcoding the /profile URL to be handled only by the Laravel application.
Example Apache 2 configuration so that Laravel processes all URLs starting with /profile (/profile/styles.css, /profile/script.js, etc.):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

An example Apache2 configuration so that Laravel only processes the URL /profile, and /profile/** would display the contents of files or directories:
# If you want the URL to be without the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/?$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

